# How did Jack know what The Master had turned the TARDIS into?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode *The Sound of Drums*. when Martha, Jack and The Doctor find the TARDIS, after Martha comments that the TARDIS sounds like it was sick.

> **The Doctor:** It can't be. No no no no no. It can't be. 
>   **Martha:** Doctor, what is it? 
>   **The Doctor:** He's cannibalized the TARDIS. 
>   **Jack:** Is this what I think it is? 
>   **The Doctor:** It's a paradox machine.

It sounds like Jack had encountered a Paradox Machine before as he is about to identify it. I am wondering if it's a part of a Time Agent's Basic Training to know what a Paradox Machine is and how to identify one, or has he encountered one before? (I haven't seen a lot of Torchwood).

Comment: The real clue about what Captain Jack thinks would be in his next line of dialogue. The Doctor has realized it's a paradox machine, but Jack might have thought of something else. This is just as possible as him believing it's a paradox machine. Though it would be nifty if he did know it was a Paradox Machine.

Answer (score 6):

There is no post 2005 tv canon episodes that expand on paradox machines, or on the technical aspects of Jack's time as a Time Agent. Much of Jacks past is shrouded in mystery. The shows both play this up to show Jack as a Doctor Lite.

Additionally, there is nothing to suggest that a paradox machine is unique to TARDI instead of being a possibility of any time machine.

Comment: Being a former Time Agent, he must have been trained in what a paradox machine does or at least might be capable of.  He's not certain, which implies that he hasn't actually encountered one before.

Comment: Also, in the First Season Jack seemed to know how to fly the TARDIS and how to repair it and add stuff, like Machro Kinetic Extrapolator